# How can I pass a username/password in the header to a SOAP WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm trying to consume a third-party web service
https://staging.identitymanagement.lexisnexis.com/identity-proofing/services/identityProofingServiceWS/v2?wsdl

I already added it as a service reference but I'm not sure how to pass the credentials for the header.

How can I make the header request match this format?

```xml
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-49" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>12345/userID</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/ oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password123</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">d+VxCZX1cH/ieMkKEr/ofA==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-08-04T20:25:04.038Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: you can pass the information using messagecontract...

Comment: Here is a good link http://aspalliance.com/805_Soap_Headers_Authentication_in_Web_Services

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is probably a smarter way, but you can add the headers manually like this:

```
var client = new IdentityProofingService.IdentityProofingWSClient();

using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
        new SecurityHeader("UsernameToken-49", "12345/userID", "password123"));
    client.invokeIdentityService(new IdentityProofingRequest());
}
```

Here, `SecurityHeader` is a custom implemented class, which needs a few other classes since I chose to use attributes to configure the XML serialization:

```
public class SecurityHeader : MessageHeader
{
    private readonly UsernameToken _usernameToken;

    public SecurityHeader(string id, string username, string password)
    {
        _usernameToken = new UsernameToken(id, username, password);
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Security"; }
    }

    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"; }
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UsernameToken));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, _usernameToken);
    }
}


[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public class UsernameToken
{
    public UsernameToken()
    {
    }

    public UsernameToken(string id, string username, string password)
    {
        Id = id;
        Username = username;
        Password = new Password() {Value = password};
    }

    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Password Password { get; set; }
}

public class Password
{
    public Password()
    {
        Type = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText";
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have not added the `Nonce` bit to the `UsernameToken` XML, but it is very similar to the `Password` one. The `Created` element also needs to be added still, but it's a simple `[XmlElement]`.

Comment: I want to have complete control over my WCF SOAP header due to the fact that my customer does not fully follow the WS-* standards. This is the perfect solution in this scenario! Thank you.

Comment: Finally i found this solution and it works great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Oguzhan KIRCALI - Can you please suggest how can i resolve same issue?

Comment: Hi, if you call a service, you can try this header in endpoint. 
Let me know about result of your try. @AbhishekTomar

<endpoint address="">
    <headers>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>yourUsername</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>2</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </headers>
</endpoint>

Comment: @Oguzhan KIRCALI ---- Error : System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type application/json;charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 474 bytes of the response were: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

Answer (score 67):

The answers above are so wrong! DO NOT add custom headers. Judging from your sample xml, it is a standard WS-Security header. WCF definitely supports it out of the box. When you add a service reference you should have basicHttpBinding binding created for you in the config file. You will have to modify it to include security element with mode TransportWithMessageCredential and message element with clientCredentialType = UserName:

```xml
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="usernameHttps">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The config above is telling WCF to expect userid/password in the SOAP header over HTTPS. Then you can set id/password in your code before making a call:

```
var service = new MyServiceClient();
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Unless this particular service provider deviated from the standard, it should work.

Comment: Thank you this would be a clean solution. I'm getting this error message: 
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "12345/userID";
System.InvalidOperationException: Object is read-only.

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199014/getting-object-is-read-only-error-when-setting-clientcredentials-in-wcf

Comment: thanks that solved that error but now I get this error
An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header 
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: aha, looks like it doesn't like extra tags that WCF adds. Replace basic binding with custom binding, and change your endpoint to reference it, it prevents WCF from adding Timestamp tag and also allows for receiving unsecured faults.
 <customBinding>
        <binding name="secureCustom">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" includeTimestamp="false"></security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

Comment: For me (VS2012, .NET 4.5, using an externally maintained SOAP service), this answer worked just fine.  Thorarin's did also, but it is serious overkill if changing one parameter in the config works as well.

Comment: Hi. I understand what u did with the web.config. What if i have a WCF being consumed by an java application. How do i check the credentials (on WCF ofc). Regards

Comment: Sir, you saved my life. Correct and cleanest solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've downvoted the answer because the example in the question specifically lists a nonce and a created timestamp in the Username token, which is part of the WS-Security specification, but is not supported by WCF out of the box. It requires custom ClientCredentials ans overrides of several other classes. I found more information on how to do this here, but am not adding as an answer yet as I have not yet tested it myself: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/24/wcf-wssecurity-and-wse-nonce-authentication

Comment: If you are using certificates and the wse username/pw then this will not work

Answer (score 2):

Adding a custom hard-coded header may work (it also may get rejected at times) but it is totally the wrong way to do it. The purpose of the WSSE is security. Microsoft released the Microsoft Web Services Enhancements 2.0 and subsequently the WSE 3.0 for this exact reason. You need to install this package (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089).

The documentation is not easy to understand, especially for those who have not worked with SOAP and the WS-Addressing. First of all the "BasicHttpBinding" is Soap 1.1 and it will not give you the same message header as the WSHttpBinding. Install the package and look at the examples. You will need to reference the DLL from WSE 3.0 and you will also need to setup your message correctly. There are a huge number or variations on the WS Addressing header. The one you are looking for is the UsernameToken configuration.

This is a longer explanation and I should write something up for everyone since I cannot find the right answer anywhere. At a minimum you need to start with the WSE 3.0 package.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it has been some years this post has been alive - but the fact is I did find it when looking for a similar issue. In our case, we had to add the username / password info to the Security header. This is different from adding header info outside of the Security headers.

The correct way to do this (for custom bindings / authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport") (as on the .Net framework version 4.6.1), is to add the Client Credentials as usual :

```
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "[username]";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "[password]";
```

and then add a "token" in the security binding element - as the username / pwd credentials would not be included by default when the authentication mode is set to certificate.

You can set this token like so:

```
    //Get the current binding 
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = client.Endpoint.Binding;
    //Get the binding elements 
    BindingElementCollection elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
    //Locate the Security binding element
    SecurityBindingElement security = elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>();

    //This should not be null - as we are using Certificate authentication anyway
    if (security != null)
    {
    UserNameSecurityTokenParameters uTokenParams = new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters();
    uTokenParams.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(uTokenParams);
    }

   client.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements.ToArray());
```

That should do it. Without the above code (to explicitly add the username token), even setting the username info in the client credentials may not result in those credentials passed to the Service.

Answer (score 2):

Answers that suggest that the header provided *in the question* are supported out of the box by WCF are incorrect. The header in the question contains a **Nonce** and a **Created** timestamp in the UsernameToken, which is an official part of the WS-Security specification that WCF does not support. **WCF only supports username and password out of the box**.

If all you need to do is add a username and password, then Sergey's answer is the least-effort approach. If you need to add any other fields, you will need to supply custom classes to support them.

A somewhat more elegant approach that I [found](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/24/wcf-wssecurity-and-wse-nonce-authentication) was to override the ClientCredentials, ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager and WSSecurityTokenizer classes to support the additional properties. I've provided a link to the blog post where the approach is discussed in detail, but here is the sample code for the overrides:

```cs
public class CustomCredentials : ClientCredentials
{
    public CustomCredentials()
    { }

    protected CustomCredentials(CustomCredentials cc)
        : base(cc)
    { }

    public override System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenManager CreateSecurityTokenManager()
    {
        return new CustomSecurityTokenManager(this);
    }

    protected override ClientCredentials CloneCore()
    {
        return new CustomCredentials(this);
    }
}

public class CustomSecurityTokenManager : ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager
{
    public CustomSecurityTokenManager(CustomCredentials cred)
        : base(cred)
    { }

    public override System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenSerializer CreateSecurityTokenSerializer(System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenVersion version)
    {
        return new CustomTokenSerializer(System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityVersion.WSSecurity11);
    }
}

public class CustomTokenSerializer : WSSecurityTokenSerializer
{
    public CustomTokenSerializer(SecurityVersion sv)
        : base(sv)
    { }

    protected override void WriteTokenCore(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer,
                                            System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken token)
    {
        UserNameSecurityToken userToken = token as UserNameSecurityToken;

        string tokennamespace = "o";

        DateTime created = DateTime.Now;
        string createdStr = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");

        // unique Nonce value - encode with SHA-1 for 'randomness'
        // in theory the nonce could just be the GUID by itself
        string phrase = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var nonce = GetSHA1String(phrase);

        // in this case password is plain text
        // for digest mode password needs to be encoded as:
        // PasswordAsDigest = Base64(SHA-1(Nonce + Created + Password))
        // and profile needs to change to
        //string password = GetSHA1String(nonce + createdStr + userToken.Password);

        string password = userToken.Password;

        writer.WriteRaw(string.Format(
        "<{0}:UsernameToken u:Id=\"" + token.Id +
        "\" xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
        "<{0}:Username>" + userToken.UserName + "</{0}:Username>" +
        "<{0}:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">" +
        password + "</{0}:Password>" +
        "<{0}:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">" +
        nonce + "</{0}:Nonce>" +
        "<u:Created>" + createdStr + "</u:Created></{0}:UsernameToken>", tokennamespace));
    }

    protected string GetSHA1String(string phrase)
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
    }

}
```

Before creating the client, you create the custom binding and manually add the security, encoding and transport elements to it. Then, replace the default ClientCredentials with your custom implementation and set the username and password as you would normally:

```
var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
    security.IncludeTimestamp = false;
    security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
    security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;

var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
encoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;

var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000; // 20 megs

binding.Elements.Add(security);
binding.Elements.Add(encoding);
binding.Elements.Add(transport);

RealTimeOnlineClient client = new RealTimeOnlineClient(binding,
    new EndpointAddress(url));

    client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Remove(client.ClientCredentials);
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomCredentials());

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have service reference of the name `localhost` in your `web.config` so you can go as follows

```
localhost.Service objWebService = newlocalhost.Service();
localhost.AuthSoapHd objAuthSoapHeader = newlocalhost.AuthSoapHd();
string strUsrName =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
string strPassword =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

objAuthSoapHeader.strUserName = strUsrName;
objAuthSoapHeader.strPassword = strPassword;

objWebService.AuthSoapHdValue =objAuthSoapHeader;
string str = objWebService.HelloWorld();

Response.Write(str);
```

Comment: This is not WCF, but an old style web service.

Comment: Thorarin, are you saying I can't consume the web service using wcf? I have to add the reference as a web reference?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are calling a web service using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, because .Net client doest support the structure of the WSLD that your are trying to consume.

In that case you can add the security credentials on the headers like:

```
<soap:Envelpe>
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand='true' xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-3DAJDJSKJDHFJASDKJFKJ234JL2K3H2K3J42'><wsse:Username>YOU_USERNAME/wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>YOU_PASSWORD</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary'>3WSOKcKKm0jdi3943ts1AQ==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2015-01-12T16:46:58.386Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
</soapHeather>
<soap:Body>
</soap:Body>


</soap:Envelope>
```

You can use SOAPUI to get the wsse Security, using the http log.

Be careful because it is not a safe scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I got a better method from here: [WCF: Creating Custom Headers, How To Add and Consume Those Headers](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1075)

> **Client Identifies Itself**
>   The goal here is to have the client provide some sort of information
>   which the server can use to determine who is sending the message. The
>   following C# code will add a header named ClientId:

```
var cl = new ActiveDirectoryClient();

var eab = new EndpointAddressBuilder(cl.Endpoint.Address);

eab.Headers.Add( AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("ClientId",       // Header Name
                                                   string.Empty,     // Namespace
                                                    "OmegaClient")); // Header Value
cl.Endpoint.Address = eab.ToEndpointAddress();

// Now do an operation provided by the service.
cl.ProcessInfo("ABC");
```

> What that code is doing is adding an endpoint header named ClientId
>   with a value of OmegaClient to be inserted into the soap header
>   without a namespace.
>
> **Custom Header in Client’s Config File**
>   There is an alternate way of
>   doing a custom header. That can be achieved in the Xml config file of
>   the client where all messages sent by specifying the custom header as
>   part of the endpoint as so:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IActiveDirectory" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:41863/ActiveDirectoryService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IActiveDirectory"
              contract="ADService.IActiveDirectory" name="BasicHttpBinding_IActiveDirectory">
            <headers>
              <ClientId>Console_Client</ClientId>
            </headers>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added customBinding to the web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomSoapBinding">
          <security includeTimestamp="false"
                    authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://test.com:443/services/testService"
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomSoapBinding"
                contract="testService.test"
                name="test" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
                      sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

After adding customBinding, I can pass username and password to client service like as follows:

```
service.ClientCridentials.UserName.UserName = "testUser";
service.ClientCridentials.UserName.Password = "testPass";
```

In this way you can pass username, password in the header to a SOAP WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in relation to this Peoplesoft issue: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/PeopleSoft%20Enterprise/2370907_1.html

I needed to set the attribute on the Soap Password, where previously the attribute was not being set on that tag.

I simply set the MessageSecurityVersion on my Custom Binding:

```
  CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
            customBinding.Name = endpointName;
            customBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            customBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            customBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            customBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
            customBinding.Elements.Add(textMessageElement);

            TransportSecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
            securityElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
            customBinding.Elements.Add(securityElement);

            // ORDER MATTERS: THIS HAS TO BE LAST!!! - HVT
            HttpsTransportBindingElement transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            transportElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            transportElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            customBinding.Elements.Add(transportElement);

            return customBinding;
```