# wcf soap PasswordText

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I need to call an SOAP service passing username and password with WSS-Type equal "PasswordText". This service is running in SoapUI

[SoapUI setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTQeJ.png)

I have coded my constructor with the credentials needed, as below picture:

[Constructor with credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSRM6.png)

I have bound the channel in this way:

[Channel Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRkBG.png)

The credentials are being sent, but I receive an error from the service telling me that the security module was not setted.

[Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsEFa.png)

I guess that the reason is a need to set WSS-Type as "PasswordText" - plain text authentication. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Links and images of code are less likely to get any responses on this site. I recommend you post the smallest possible relevant bits of the actual code you can, into your question.

Comment: You can try changing `MessageSecurityVersion`, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200908/how-to-set-password-type-passwordtext-in-the-wsse-security-header-with-wcf).