# How to prefix a XmlRoot object in c# for Serialise XML?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, win-universal-app

I need make a Header for SOAP request. After search, I success to generate my Header request in XML but i need a prefix on my XML tag.

Actually, I have generated this :

```
<TimeStamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TimeStamp-2">
   <Created>2016-03-22T10:10:55.710Z</Created>
   <Expires>2016-03-22T11:10:55.710Z</Expires>
</TimeStamp>
```

And I need to have that :

```
<wsu:TimeStamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TimeStamp-2">
   <Created>2016-03-22T10:10:55.710Z</Created>
   <Expires>2016-03-22T11:10:55.710Z</Expires>
</wsu:TimeStamp>
```

I was inspired by this topic ([How can I pass a username/password in the header to a SOAP WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028014/how-can-i-pass-a-username-password-in-the-header-to-a-soap-wcf-service)) for create my class and generate my XML.

Here, there is my version :

```
class SecurityHeader : MessageHeader
{

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Security"; }
    }

    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"; }
    }

    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
        XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TimeStamp));
        serializer1.Serialize(Console.Out, new TimeStamp(), ns);

    }
}

[XmlRoot("TimeStamp",Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public class TimeStamp
{
    public TimeStamp()
    {
        Id = "TimeStamp-2";
        Created = new Created() { Value = Created.GenerateTimeStampCreation() };
        Expires = new Expires() { Value = Expires.GenerateTimeStampExpiration() };
    }

    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Created Created { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Expires Expires { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

1. Your `<Created>` and `<Expires>` elements are not in the `"wsu"` namespace, instead they are not in any namespace.  You need to inform `XmlSerializer` of this by setting [`[XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`[XmlElement(Namespace="")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. To force the `Id` attribute to have an explicit namespace, you need to set [`[XmlAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. You have a typo in your namespaces.  Your desired XML has the namespace `xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"` but sometimes you do `"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"`.  To avoid this sort of mistake, you can make a `public const string` that contains the correct namespace rather than retyping the string multiple times.

Thus your fixed `TimeStamp` class would look like:

```
[XmlRoot("TimeStamp", Namespace = TimeStamp.WsuNamespace)]
public class TimeStamp
{
    public const string WsuNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";

    public TimeStamp()
    {
        Id = "TimeStamp-2";
        Created = new Created() { Value = Created.GenerateTimeStampCreation() };
        Expires = new Expires() { Value = Expires.GenerateTimeStampExpiration() };
    }

    [XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)] // Indicates this attribute is explicitly in the same namespace as the parent class
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] // Indicates this element is not in any namespace
    public Created Created { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] // Indicates this element is not in any namespace
    public Expires Expires { get; set; }
}
```

And in your write method do:

```
    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("wsu", TimeStamp.WsuNamespace);
        XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TimeStamp));
        serializer1.Serialize(writer, new TimeStamp(), ns);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I resolve my problem by myself. My solution is similar at your first issue. I use the method OnWriteHeaderContents (but I didn't specify on this topic, sorry) . I'm in a little rush, so I edit my message in the week for explains and study your other issues for improve my code and the header generate. Thank you @dbc