# Set Type PasswordText on Password Attribute in C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, soap, xmlhttprequest

I got an error when I execute my CSharp application.

> Unhandled Exception:
>       System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: An invalid security token was provided (An error happened processing a Username Token "{0}")
>     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message, System.Net.WebResponse response, System.IO.Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) <0x403b5b40 + 0x00d7b> in :0

This is my soapheader xml request.

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

This is the code snippet in my C# source codes.

```
private String passwordField;

public string Password
{
    get { return this.passwordField; }
    set { this.passwordField = value; }
}

public UsernameToken(string username, string password)
{
    this.Username = username;
    this.Password = password;
}
```

I suspected that the cause of this issue is that I didn't add namespace **PasswordText** in password attribute.

I added namespace PasswordText above Password property but I got an error.

```
[XmlAttribute("Password", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText")]
public string Password
{
  get { return this.passwordField; }
  set { this.passwordField = value; }
}
```

How can I add namespace PasswordText in Password attribute in my C# code?

Thanks guys!

Comment: The namespace soapenv is not defined.

Comment: hi @jdweng, how can I add PasswordText type to Password attribute? Thanks for fast response. :)

Comment: The error is occurring before you added PasswordText.  You can validate the xml using VS.  Using menu Project : 
Add New Item : Xml File.  Paste Xml into window.  Errors will show up lie any compiler error in the Error List window.

Comment: hi @jdweng, the xml request is working properly. I successfully sent requests through soapui. Thanks :)

Comment: When I removed the PasswordText in Password attribute in xml request via soapui, I got the same error when sending the request.

Comment: See examples in pdf file : http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf

Comment: Thanks jdweng. My xml request works properly, do you have an idea how to add PasswordText in password attribute in C#?

Comment: The password is not an attribute.  It is the innertext of the element.  So use  [XmlText]

Comment: hi @jdweng, thanks for the help. I fixed it and got the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028014/how-can-i-pass-a-username-password-in-the-header-to-a-soap-wcf-service

Comment: How about this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028014/how-can-i-pass-a-username-password-in-the-header-to-a-soap-wcf-service ?

Comment: Hi @anete.anetes, that is the solution that I used. Thank you :)