# Where does IContextChannel client.InnerChannel come from this WSDL?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsse

I am trying to overwrite the headers to have the **push** method called in this WebService but the IContextChannel InnerChannel argument does not exist in the definition.

I made the SecurityHeader class as indicated by the response of the article in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16031437/11505984. But I can't understand where InnerChannel comes from.

```
try
{
    TransmissionService transmission = new TransmissionService();
    using (new OperationContextScope(transmission.InnerChannel))
    {
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
            new SecurityHeader("UsernameToken-8", "12345/userID", "password123"));
        transmission.publish(new Transmission());
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var message = e.Message;
}
```

I'm having the following error: TransmissionService does not contain a definition for InnerChannel and no extension method.

Can someone explain to me what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try TransmissionService casting to IContextChannel:

```
try
{
    TransmissionService transmission = new TransmissionService();
    using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel) transmission))
    {
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
            new SecurityHeader("UsernameToken-8", "12345/userID", "password123"));
        transmission.publish(new Transmission());
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var message = e.Message;
}
```

Maybe these links will help you too:

https://trycatch.me/adding-custom-message-headers-to-a-wcf-service-using-inspectors-behaviors/

https://github.com/NaveeenSemwal/add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call

https://github.com/lamronby/wcfextrasplus

https://github.com/vh-vahan/WcfSecurityHeader

https://github.com/melomenic/wcfheaderinjectionbehavior