# System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors vs System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint.Behaviors

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is a question dealing with the internals of the .net framework.  While working to consume a Java SOAP web service I had to alter the endpoint behaviors to both add a custom SOAP header (the web service required a nonce) and manipulate the reply so the WCF could properly deserialize the response.

While looking at code examples one used the ServiceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors while another used ServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.  After some testing it appears that both properties have the same affect and can be interchanged which leads the question, what is the difference between the two?

Code for an example:

Custom endpoint behavior:

```
public class ApplyClientEndpointBehaviour<T> : IEndpointBehavior where T : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public ApplyClientEndpointBehaviour(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    private readonly T _item;

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(_item);
    }

   public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // Nothing special here
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        // Nothing special here
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        // Nothing special here
    }
}
```

Then

```
var client = new <wcf client child class of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase generated through Add Service Reference>

client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ApplyClientEndpointBehaviour<SomeIClientMessageInspector>(new SomeIClientMessageInspector()));
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ApplyClientEndpointBehaviour<AnotherIClientMessageInspector>(new AnotherIClientMessageInspector()));
```

Assigning `SomeIClientMessageInspector` and `AnotherIClientMessageInspector` to either `Endpoint.Behaviors` or `Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors` causes no change in actual functionality.  Both can be assigned to one or the other interchangeably with no change in behavior of the service endpoint.  Which leads to the question of, what if any thing is different between the 2 properties or was one added and the other left for backwards comparability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the decompiled source, `EndpointBehaviors` just returns the `Behaviors` collection.

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public KeyedCollection<System.Type, IEndpointBehavior> EndpointBehaviors
{
  [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
  {
    return (KeyedCollection<System.Type, IEndpointBehavior>) this.Behaviors;
  }
}
```

`EndpointBehaviors` is available since .NET Framework 4.5 and portable platforms, while `Behaviors` is available since 3.0. My guess is that it is the result of merging APIs of Desktop and portable platforms.

Comment: Thanks.  This answers the question of why the behavior was the same.